# Ordenar lista de mayor a menor en un ciclo

Tags: python, python-3.x

buenas tardes, tengo una duda como puedo hacer que aparezcan todos los datos ingresados en esta lista de mayor a menor (numero) y que tal numero pertenece a tal indice. Tengo esto pero no me funciona.
Lo que va adentro de la lista lo digita el usuario.Saludos

```
    while i < listaMesas[0]:
mesaMasFrecuente = listaMesas[0]
for numeroMesa in listaMesas:
    if numeroMesa[indexOrdenes] > mesaMasFrecuente[indexOrdenes]:
        mesaMasFrecuente = numeroMesa
        i+=1
print(f"** REPORTE: MESA MAS SOLICITADA **: ")
print(f"MESAS(S): {mesaMasFrecuente[indexMesas]} , 
{mesaMasFrecuente[indexOrdenes]} ")
```

Comment: Intenta corregir la identación, y te falta la declaración de `listaMesas`

Comment: Lo que quiero es meter en un ciclo mi lista, esa lista es digitada por un usuario. Yo lo que quiero es que me saque el numero mas alto del que usuario registro y baje hasta el mas bajo. Pero que en cada vuelta diga este numero es de tal posición.

Comment: @Keylor te recomiendo hacer lo que se te ha sugerido antes de dar más información.

Comment: Esa indentación en Python nunca te va a funcionar. Por otra parte, decir `no me funciona` es un poco vago. Procura incluir en tus preguntas qué es lo que ves al ejecutar tu código y qué debería salir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy casi seguro que respondi otra pregunta con ese codigo tuyo. Te pongo aqui el fragmento especifico que ordena la lista. Es un algoritmo muy conocido. El metodo de la burbuja

```
listaMesasOrdenadas = listaMesas.copy()

for i in range(len(listaMesas) - 1):
    for j in range(len(listaMesas) - 1):
        if listaMesasOrdenadas[j][indexOrdenes] < listaMesasOrdenadas[j + 1][indexOrdenes]:
            listaMesasOrdenadas[j], listaMesasOrdenadas[j + 1] = listaMesasOrdenadas[j + 1], listaMesasOrdenadas[j]

print("** REPORTE: FRECUENCIA DE MESAS (Mayor a menor frecuencia)**: ")
for mesa in listaMesasOrdenadas:
    print(f"MESA: {mesa[indexMesas]} , {mesa[indexOrdenes]} ")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono